# How to remove extra comma when concatenating strings

Tags: powershell

```
$folders = Get-ChildItem | where {$_.Attributes -match 'Directory'}
foreach ($items in $folders)
{
$type = $items.name
$cat = $cat + "," + "$type/*.$type
}
$cat
```

This is supposed to print text, text but instead it adds an extra comma I understand due to how the script is written it will cause it to add the extra comma. I am trying to figure out if there is another way to write this that removes the extra comma.

This is written with concatenation because of off the top of my head it seemed simpler because everything is under one variable and what is being passed to works well in this situation.

Comment: Don't have a Windows computer handy, but I think `$cat = $folders | select -Property name | -join ','`?

Comment: @smarx would this go inside the foreach statement? If I put that statement by itself I get an error on the -join part saying “Expressions are only allowed as the first element of a pipeline”

Comment: Ah, sorry. Installing PowerShell on my Mac now to figure it out. :-)

Comment: Added an answer that's actually tested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
$cat = (Get-ChildItem | where {$_.Attributes -match 'Directory'}).Name -join ","
```

**EDIT**

I'm trying to understand the comment and question edit. Maybe this is what you want?

```
(gci -dir) | select {"$($_.Name)/*.$($_.Name)"}
```

**EDIT 2**

I'm not good at PowerShell, but putting it all together, at least this seems to work:

```
$cat = ((gci -dir -name) | select @{Name="Item";Expression={"$($_)/*.$($_)"}}).Item -join ","
```

**EDIT 3**

This is finally starting to look like a good solution:

```
$cat = ((gci -dir -name) | foreach {"$($_)/*.$($_)"}) -join ","
```

Comment: this does work but I was using the variables out from it would and that would no longer work. I was able to simplify the it, and have changed he question to reflect.

Comment: What? I couldn't understand those two sentences. I see your edit, but I'm not sure what you're trying to do. Can you give a sample output?

Comment: two folders in the main folders called css and one called js
trying to ouput this css/*.css, js/*.js

Comment: This works perfectly, thanks for the help. Can you explain what the $ outside of the parentheses does?

Comment: String interpolation. `$($_)` gets replaced with the string in `$_`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're on a newer PowerShell:

```
(Get-ChildItem -Directory) -join ', '

(gci -dir) -join ', '
```

Older / more serious:

```
(Get-ChildItem | Where-Object { $_.PsIsContainer } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name) -join ', '
```

Because why not:

```
$OFS=', ';"$(gci -di)"
```